# extracting JSESSIONID from document.cookie

Tags: xss, javascript, java, cookies, csrf

I was trying cookie stealing on a java and spring based web application.
Normally, a cookie can be obtained through `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>`,
but in the above code, cookie is not alerted.

Burpsuite and tamperdata tools are showing this cookie: `jsessionid=XXXXXXX..XXX`

Is there any way to catch cookies client-side through javascript?

Answer (score 4):

You can read the values of cookies using `document.cookie` or other client side solutions only if that particular cookie is not flagged as [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) (assuming the browser you're using supports this flag).